# Call *.pyc from a .py script with paramaters in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, remote-access, py2exe, pyc

I have got a *.pyc script that is used remotely to update a component. At the moment it is called manually by console command for every component - which is to me quite un-handy. 
Additionally the people that use it do have to install python on their local machine for that which is what i want to avoid by building a .py script and the build an exe with py2exe.

Is there an easy way to call the *.pyc with parameters in a loop for several ip addresses in a .py file? And is it actually possible to avoid the installation of the python interpreter on the local machine with that?
The command used at the moment is as follows:

```
scriptname.pyc -a *IPADDRESS* -t filename -u name -p password
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `*.pyc` file will share your `sys.args` flags if you do a normal `import scriptname` (which can be used to load `.pyc` files as well). It's one way of solving it. You can load python files via string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865882/using-newly-installed-modules-without-restarting-an-interactive-session/23865944#23865944 or if it's in the same importpath as your current script, just do a normal import. Should work. `sys.args.insert(0, '-a *IPADDRESS*')` for instance just before you import.

Comment: Thanks for that.

Comment: Just for my understanding: If I import that file will it actually execute the routines in it? It should send out the commands to multiple IP adresses. So my initial idea would be importing in a loop and adjust the parameters? Also: If i  use 'sys.args.insert(0, '-a *IPADDRESS*')' i would guess that i can just add the user and password paramters in the brackets? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It will. Depending on how you've programmed the module. If you have a `if __name__ == '__main__':` it won't execute, because it's being imported and not executed. Usually you create a `def main()` or something similar that you execute manually after you've done the import.